# Add sound to a button in html

Tags: javascript, html

Trying to add a sound to a button, can´t figure out what´s wrong.
Is there any other ways to do it?

**HTML**

```
<audio id="myAudio">
   <source href="url"="http://lab.wijkmanska.se/webbteknik/te13/mattias_martinsson/V08/KnappMattias (1).wav" type="audio/wav">
</audio>
<button type="button" onclick="aud_play_pause()">Play/Pause</button>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function aud_play_pause() {
  var myAudio = document.getElementById("myAudio");
  if (myAudio.paused) {
    myAudio.play();
  } else {
    myAudio.pause();
  }
}
```

Comment: This isn't valid `href="url"="http://lab.wijkmanska.se/webbteknik/te13/mattias_martinsson/V08/KnappMattias (1).wav"`

Comment: An answer to this question has been made here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18826147/javascript-audio-play-on-click

Answer (score 1):

Working example over here.

```
var playBtn = document.getElementById('play');
var stopBtn = document.getElementById('stop');

var playSound = function() {
audio.play();
};

playBtn.addEventListener('click', playSound, false);
stopBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){audio.pause()}, false);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dsuket/jTh3v/

You need to change your audio path since it's invalid.

edit: I changed the audio path for you. Fiddle updated with your sound.

Answer (score 1):

The simple fix to your example is to correct the source tag to src="path"

```
<source src="http://lab.wijkmanska.se/webbteknik/te13/mattias_martinsson/V08/KnappMattias (1).wav" type="audio/wav">
```