# Audio will not play - JS -

Tags: javascript, html

Struggled with this for hours - Can't seem to get the audio file to play once I click an HTML element.

```js
var bb = document.querySelector(".soundfile");

function playAudio() {
  bb.play();
}


document.querySelector(".btn-hold").addEventListener("click", playAudio);
```

```html
<audio class="soundfile">
  <sound src="sound.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>

<button class="btn-new"><i class="ion-ios-plus-outline"></i>New game</button>
<button class="btn-roll"><i class="ion-ios-loop"></i>Roll dice</button>
<button class="btn-hold"><i class="ion-ios-download-outline"></i>Hold</button>
```

this is different to other questions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript Audio Play on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18826147/javascript-audio-play-on-click)

Comment: I'm a little confused by your code. If you're asking about playing a sound file from a click, why are you showing buttons labeled "new game", "roll dice" and "hold"? Can you create a plain [mcve] instead?

Comment: it should be `<source>` not `<sound>`. No?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I imagine OP wants to play a sound when you click the "Hold" button. There's enough information here to understand the problem (which YongQuan has solved above)

Comment: As do I, and the [mcve] request is not just for us, but also for James himself: 99.9% of the time simply the exercise of creating that minimal example makes you discover the _actual_ problem all on your own, even if you already had your SO question written up.

Answer (score 3):

It should be `<source>`, not `<sound>`.

```
<audio class="soundfile">
  <source src="sound.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

It should be working after you change to the correct element.

If it's still not working, then there might be a problem in some other part of your code and we have not enough information to help you diagnose that.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `<sound>` tag with `<source>`