# Execute audio player on server when link is clicked on web page

Tags: html, apache, raspbian

I can't seem to figure out how to open an mp3 File on my Webserver.
If I just href the Song (Code below) it opens it on the Client I am accessing it from.
I want the Song to play on the Webserver even if I access the html page from another Device.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<a href="Song.mp3">Song</a>

</body>
</html>
```

How do I solve this?
I am using a Raspberry Pie, Apache, VLC (to play mp3)
Thanks for your support :D

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18826567/7351855

Comment: This has nothing to do with my question. My mp3 file opens fine when I click on the link. I just can't figure out how to always execute the mp3 file on the server (Raspberry) instead of it opening on the client device as I click on the html link.

Comment: So you don't want to use your browser just via terminal, right?

Comment: Yes I'd like this command to be executed on the Server when clicking the link: vlc Song.mp3

Comment: So something totally different. Is this what you want?: start http web server on rpi, sends html to client, when client clicks to the button play audio?

Comment: Oh, I see, you have apache server, so use php system() function http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php

Comment: I changed this in the html: <a href="script.php">Song</a>
And created a php file but it is still not working. If I execute the php File on the server itself it works but it doesn't if I click the link.     Here the php code: <?php 
function bb()
{
exec('vlc Song1.mp3');
}
bb();
?>

Comment: I posted answer instead of comment, is it possible to remove answer? xd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because I couldn't execute the command directly I had to create a script which reacts to created files.

```
<?php 
    shell_exec('touch Song1.txt');
    ?>
```

Song.sh :

```
while  [ -f run.txt ]
do
if [ -f Song1.txt ];
then  
        cvlc --play-and-exit songs/song.mp3
        rm -f Song1.txt
fi
done
```

Comment: That's also solution but CPU consumption is high, right? Add some sleep, for example `sleep 0.1` under the `fi` or use `inotify`

Comment: I edited my answer with `inotify`, it can use less CPU.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

index.html:

`<a href="/script.php">Song</a>`

script.php:

`<?php 
exec('export DISPLAY=:0; cvlc songs/Song1.mp3');
?>`

---

Edit:

Solution with `inotifywait` which can be CPU consumption friendly:

Php:

```
<?php 
    shell_exec('cat Song1.txt');
 ?>
```

Bash:

```
touch Song1.txt  
while  [ -f run.txt ]
do
    inotifywait --event=close_nowrite Song1.txt
    cvlc --play-and-exit songs/song.mp3
done
```

Comment: no still not working. Gives me a blank page and nothing executes. The Button obviously doesn't make a connection to the script because the php script itself works.

Comment: @Oromis Blank page is all right, because php doesn't print anything. Is path in `exec() ` correct?

Comment: yes because the cli command: php script.php starts the mp3 with vlc correctly

Comment: @Oromis Ohh, does it start graphic interface?

Comment: @Oromis That's the problem put there `cvlc` instead of `vlc`

Comment: It works with php script.php but not when clicking the html link. The html page then loads endlessly

Comment: sadly no difference

Comment: @Oromis Can you connect via ssh to your pi? Try run this command via ssh, it can be suchlike execute from php.

Comment: export DISPLAY=:0; cvlc songs/Song1.mp3 worked via ssh

Comment: @Oromis And php script.php via ssh?

Comment: @Oromis I tried it too with php builtin server and without `export DISPLAY=:0;` and it worked for me.

Comment: @Oromis I believe that it's apache problem because today I was working with apache too and thing which works with nginx doesn't work with apache.

Comment: @Oromis Or if you need just this you can you one of python http web server libraries. For example Tornado or Flask.