# Play sound when button clicked html

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I want to make that when you click on a button it makes a sound, i tryed this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var audio = new Audio('audio_file.mp3');
</script>
<button id="Draw/Chat" onclick="audio.play();" type="button" style="font-weight:bold; background: none rgb(0, 255, 0); border: none; color: rgb(255, 255, 255); box-shadow: none; height: 52px; width: 110px; left: 190px; top: 80px; border-radius: 5px; cursor: pointer; position: absolute;">Draw/Chat</button>
```

Comment: Please, before posting a question try to check whether it has been asked (and answered) before, using the search function: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+play+sound+on+button+click

Comment: ... also consider that the audio file might require some time to be loaded therefore it is advisable to check whether it is ready to play before tying to execute it.

Comment: ... finally, you might want to check whether the path to your audio file is correct. In your example 'audio_file.mp3' is supposed to be in the same folder where your HTML page is; is that the case?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript Audio Play on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18826147/javascript-audio-play-on-click)

Answer (score -1):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Audio</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <script>
      function play() {
        var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
        audio.play();
      }
    </script>

    <input type="button" value="PLAY" onclick="play()">
    <audio id="audio" src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-audio/t-rex-roar.mp3"></audio>

  </body>
</html>
```

Try this code, please

Comment: this didn't work :/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18826147/javascript-audio-play-on-click

I checked and it worked fine, please check again.

Comment: @KpStar what's the point of copying and pasting an already existing answer, without adding anything new/different to it, rather than simply linking it in a comment?

Answer (score -1):

Don't use a semicolon in the onclick function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var audio = new Audio('audio_file.mp3');
</script>
<button id="Draw/Chat" onclick="audio.play()" type="button" style="font-weight:bold; background: none rgb(0, 255, 0); border: none; color: rgb(255, 255, 255); box-shadow: none; height: 52px; width: 110px; left: 190px; top: 80px; border-radius: 5px; cursor: pointer; position: absolute;">Draw/Chat</button>
```