# How do I make a song play when I click a button?

Tags: html

I currently have some code where a song plays with the controls but I want to make a button that matches the theme of the website is this possible or no?

Here is my code

```
<audio controls autoplay loop>
    <source src="Main Theme.mp3" type="audio/ogg">
    <embed src="Main Theme.mp3" autostart="true" loop="true" hidden="true"> 
  </audio>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript Audio Play on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18826147/javascript-audio-play-on-click)

Answer (score 0):

Create a button and add an action to this button. The action could be javascript inside of a  tag, which finds the audio and plays it.

This should solve your problem: [Javascript Audio Play on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18826147/javascript-audio-play-on-click)