# How to play sound Whenever I recieve new notification witj reactJs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, audio, push-notification, get

actually I'm working on reactJs project with laravel on backend I want to play sound whenever I recieve notification I tried but I didn't get a solution.
this is my code :

```
  useEffect(() => {
    let statusInterval = setInterval(() => {
    getData();

  }, 10000)
  return () => {
    clearInterval(statusInterval);
  }
  }, [])

  async function getData() {
    let result = await fetch(`${API_ENDPOINT}/api/listComplain`);
    result = await result.json();
    setData(result)
  }
```

I want also to know if there's another way better that setInterval to get data
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18826147/javascript-audio-play-on-click  Repurpose the code here to fire whenever your notification event fires?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Classic would have been to use web sockets for this instant notification notices to clients. But this requires some setup and knowledge. Actually I wrote a service that you can POST to it and it will send data (like a string)  to the clients, which is what you need. https://rejax.io .